# Active Directory Constraint Violation

Tags: active-directory

I am trying to modify the attribute "description" for a user. I am modifying the user via Java (netscape LDAP SDK). While doing so, I am getting the error with the error code: 19[Constraint Violation].

Now, I liked to see what constraint that got violated. I couldn't able to figure out where and how to look. I want to debug by starting looking into the logs why it is failing.

Any pointer would be helpful.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286760? If the SDK mistakenly assumes the property supports multiple values while it really doesn't.

Comment: I tried in another AD machine and able to update the description attribute of the user object through the same code. I doubt the issue is with SDK. Looks like some configuration or environment issue but don't know how to proceed further. How one can look into the logs for Constraint Violation related error?